# Blender 2.68: No Audio in runtime.exe after export

Tags: audio, export, game-engine, blender

I have an issue with my audio not working in my runtime.exe after I export.  The in editor player works fine, so I'm not sure if there is a bug or if its something I've missed.

I've watched every video I could find on YouTube about how to setup sound actuators properly. I've read the documentation on them as well. I also first started having this issue in blender 2.66 so I decided to update to the current version 2.68. The issue remains. I have also tried using the 32bit as oppose to the 64bit I would normally run. nothing.

```
Blender 2.68 64bit
OS=Windows 7 Pro 64-bit(6,1 build 7600)
System Manufacturer=MSI
System Model=MS-7599
Processor=AMD Phenom(tm) II X4 965 Processor (4CPUs),~3.4GHz
Memory=20480MB RAM
```

Comment: There is not nearly enough information in this question for you to stand any chance of getting an answer.

Comment: I would love to give you more info but there are no errors or warnings in debug... I setup my actuators for sound and link them to there triggers IE Jump,walk,run etc. Those triggers work when the game is played inside blender. when exported as a runtime.exe everything works fine except for sound. the sound files are simple .wav files. they are kept in the same folder as the rest of my assets in there own sounds folder. Is there a method to pack them as I do with my textures? I can't seem to find anything stating that I have to pack them or if there is even a way to do so.